# Not able to access Sharepoint Central Administration

Tags: 2010, central-administration, installation

I installed Sharepoint Server 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2 machine (inside VMWare). The installation was successful and by default the site was opened

The site URL is something like:

```
http://win-1gduujtl9rg/_layouts/templatepick.aspx
```

This screen opens into a site where we can chose the template such as Team Site, Blank Site Collection etc but not central admin screen. The same site is getting open when I'm trying to access Sharepoint Admin from Start >> All Programs >> Sharepoint Central Administration Site.

How to access Sharepoint Central Admin Site? Do I need to select any template and then the C.A. would be accessible?

Answer (score 3):

As I added the sharepoint site as a local trusted zone under IE Security Settings, I was able to access the Sharepoint Central Admin Site.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used the Farm Configuration Wizard so the central administration site has been deployed on a dedicated Web Application with a random port number.

Make sure you have a relevant entry within IIS and that nothing is using the port selected for that web application on the server.

Some browsers (eg: Firefox) have issue accessing non :80 port unless you add them within the about:config parameters as trusted but regarding IE it's not an issue.

You should also make sure that you disable the loopback check which might give you authentication issue (among other problems).